# Having a problem with handling errors on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, error-handling

Well, after quite some research, I've figured out I have no idea what is wrong with my code. This is a Newton's Method optimization code that I am working on, and I want to test it on several functions on a for loop on another program, along with several other optimization methods, but there is a problem on a certain function that just won't let the code keep on going to test everything.

The thing is that the Newton's method requires a matrix not to be singular in order to solve a system, and on this problematic function, that matrix ends up being singular at some point, and I get an error message telling me that and stopping the whole process. I knew nothing about try and except error handling up until this point, so after some research I figured it out and implemented it on my code to try and avoid this error, however, it will still stop the entire program because of the error, would anyone take a look at it for me?

This is the code for the problematic part:

```
while np.dot(grad(x),grad(x)) > 10**(-4):
        if f(x+a*p) <= f(x)+c1*a*np.dot(grad(x),p):
            x = x+a*p
            try:
                p = -np.linalg.solve(hess(x),grad(x))
            except:
                break
            k = k+1
        else:
            a = 0.9*a
        if k >= 100:
            break
return [x, f(x),grad(x)]
```

hess(x) ends at some point being a singular matrix and giving me an exception error, but the code won't attempt to not do the try block and do the except block in this situation as I think it should, what is going on?

I've tried on a smaller problem like

```
i = 0
while i < 10:
    if 2 < 3:
        try:
            -np.linalg.solve(A,b)
        except:
            print(9)
            break
    i = i+1
```

with A a singular matrix, and it works just fine, by just printing one "9", so why on the main program this won't happen at all? Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that I call this function on another program or something like that?

I could try and get around this problem by having an if statement testing if the matrix is singular beforehand and breaking the loop if so, but I feel like that would be quite costy for an iteration, so I would like to avoid it to better compare the methods later on, so I want to avoid that as much as possible.

This is what I get when I execute my code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-1-31bd7312c08f>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/CLIENTE/Desktop/Coisas/Estudos 2.0/Ñ Linear/Testes.py', wdir='C:/Users/CLIENTE/Desktop/Coisas/Estudos 2.0/Ñ Linear')

  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 704, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py", line 108, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "C:/Users/CLIENTE/Desktop/Coisas/Estudos 2.0/Ñ Linear/Testes.py", line 52, in <module>
    effer = método(dado)

  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\Desktop\Coisas\Estudos 2.0\Ñ Linear\Método_de_Newton.py", line 27, in MétodoDeNewton
    p = -np.linalg.solve(hess(x),grad(x))

  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 394, in solve
    r = gufunc(a, b, signature=signature, extobj=extobj)

  File "C:\Users\CLIENTE\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\linalg\linalg.py", line 89, in _raise_linalgerror_singular
    raise LinAlgError("Singular matrix")

LinAlgError: Singular matrix
```

Comment: Is the `return` statement supposed to be inside the loop? It needs to have the same indentation as the rest of the loop body.

Comment: Are you sure the exception is happening on that line? Show the traceback.

Comment: Just fixed the return! I just made a mistake when formatting.

Comment: What is a traceback? And yeah, am really sure that is the line, it is the one that appears on the error thing.

Comment: When you get an exception that isn't caught, it prints a stack trace showing where the error happened. Paste that into the question.

Comment: Ah, okay, did it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried catching the fully-qualified name of the Exception?

```py
while np.dot(grad(x),grad(x)) > 10**(-4):
        if f(x+a*p) <= f(x)+c1*a*np.dot(grad(x),p):
            x = x+a*p
            try:
                p = -np.linalg.solve(hess(x),grad(x))
            # HEY! Look here.
            except np.linalg.LinAlgError:
                break
            k = k+1
        else:
            a = 0.9*a
        if k >= 100:
            break
return [x, f(x),grad(x)]
```

Comment: I tried something similar while I was still trying to figure out more about try-except, and it didn't work, and I just tested on yours, and yeah, same thing.

Comment: Try wrapping the entire while loop in try-except and see if the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Oh, I didn't think of trying that at all.

Comment: But I just tried it out, both on the whole while function insde the Newton Method file, and inside the while function that is testing every method, but no good, the same error over and over again.

Comment: Also tried it outside the loop that is testing every method, and well, it worked, it stopped when it got to that error after all ther prints I made it do.